# Substract background from static image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a board game like chess. I have 2 pictures of it shot from the bird perspective, like:

[image]

Each of the corners of the image have a marker<sup>1</sup>, that helps me to warp the 2 pictures so that even though they might have been shot from a slightly different perspective, they afterwards look mostly identical.

One of these images has all of the board game figures on it in a certain position and the other image/ picture does not.

Now after I use the markers as my new corners in a new image and warp both pictures, I want to only get have the board game figures (so basically after the warp, I want to have the difference of the two pictures).

My problem now is that a simple `mat1-mat2` or `cv::substract` doesn't work since it's way to precise and if the warp of these pictures is not 100% perfect the result doesn't help at all.

I want to build an array, consisting of the positions of the board game figures, which means that if my idea would work I might have an easier time finding the figures. **What would be the correct way to achieve this?** Is background subtraction even the right thing to do in this case?

(Please note that I don't want to swap my board game figures with markers. The markers on the corners are already a compromise for me.

---

<sup>1</sup>I am looking forward to using Aruco for this, if you suggest an alternative I might as well try it.

Comment: Check this [paper](http://www.oipaz.net/Carta-Corsolini.pdf). It may not be to the board game you are looking for.. but it may give you some ideas. For [Go](https://github.com/CmdrDats/igoki), for example, if you know the exactly location of the board, you can calculate the positions where the stones may be.. and check this specific location for a stone.

Comment: Instead of doing the comparison between two images, have you, instead, tried using a [line transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) to detect the bounds of each square? This would give you each individual tile on the game board. You could then slice out the tiles and use [cascade classification](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) to identify the types of pieces.

Comment: Well the picture will look a little bit like this afterwards https://i.imgur.com/k0UxRgo.png since I want to find the board game figures and the "borders" aswell. I hope Hough Line can help me build a grid with this, the borders might be a problem I guess. So the approach would be to use Hough Line Transform, this gives me the lines, I slice them and then check each of those slices seperatly?

Comment: Have a look at [image registration](http://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Image Registration](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d61/group__reg.html#gsc.tab=0).

I adapted the following code from the [OpenCV samples](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/reg/samples/map_test.cpp)

Given two different images of the chessboard (here I took you original image and warped a little bit)

[image]
[image]

You can *register* them, obtaining this as resulting image:

[image]

With this difference between the two:

[image]

You can see that the chessboard is aligned pretty well. The registration already takes care of the different point of views.

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\reg\mappergradproj.hpp>
#include <opencv2\reg\mapperpyramid.hpp>
#include <opencv2\reg\mapprojec.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::reg;

int main(int, char**)
{
    Mat img1 = imread("D:\\SO\\temp\\chess.JPG");
    Mat img2 = imread("D:\\SO\\temp\\chess2.png");

    img1.convertTo(img1, CV_64FC3);
    img2.convertTo(img2, CV_64FC3);

    MapperGradProj mapper;
    MapperPyramid mappPyr(mapper);

    Ptr<Map> mapPtr;
    mappPyr.calculate(img1, img2, mapPtr);

    Mat dest;
    MapProjec* mapProj = dynamic_cast<MapProjec*>(mapPtr.get());
    mapProj->normalize();
    mapProj->inverseWarp(img2, dest);

    // Show difference

    Mat image1, image2;
    img1.convertTo(image1, CV_32FC3);
    img2.convertTo(image2, CV_32FC3);

    cvtColor(image1, image1, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cvtColor(image2, image2, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    Mat imgDiff;
    img1.copyTo(imgDiff);
    imgDiff -= img2;
    imgDiff /= 2.f;
    imgDiff += 128.f;

    Mat imgSh;
    imgDiff.convertTo(imgSh, CV_8UC3);
    imshow("Diff", imgSh);

    dest.convertTo(dest, CV_8UC3);
    imshow("Dest", dest);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I`m not quite an expert, but I'd suggest you to use exacly cv:subtract. It is precise, but I believe the biggest difference would be where the pieces are located (biggest blobs).
To filter the eventual unwanted noise, you can use some filters on the result (cv::bilateralFilter, etc). Or, you could just try to earch for differeces in the image looking the results in a 10x10 window, for instance (window size must vary based on the images resolution).

Here is a link about smothing images, that might help you to use cv::subtract to get what you want:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html

This link might help you with further info about motion detection (basically is what you want, to get the pieces movement, right?)
https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/research/motion/motion.html

Comment: Thank you but I guess I have to admit the comments might be correct. Maybe detecting the grid, slicing and checking every slice is the better way. I do appreciate your help though :)

Comment: I believe Nick Cano, from the comments have a nice solution! I`ve just voted him up :)