# How can I detect if there is a piece on chess square or not?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have to detect a chess board and I do that as shown in this picture:

[image]

I divided this image in 64 sub-images which represent the black and white chess squares, like:

[image]

How can I check whether these sub-images (each square) contains a chess piece?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900409/substract-background-from-static-image/33902199#33902199). If you have an empty chessboard you should able to get the chess pieces from the difference from the two images.

Comment: Object Detection using Haar feature-based cascade classifiers is an effective object detection method. Use OpenCV to train your models for empty white, black and with pieces on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to refine your squares detection, because you have some white region in the black and vice-versa. To do this quickly you can just crop a smaller ROI in the center of the square, assuming most of the piece will be in the center.

For the actual detection there are all kinds of simple options, which I guess will work perfectly fine in your case. Don't need to go to sophisticated feature detection and machine learning.

Options:

- If you know the color of the square, use some threshold to find the piece.
- You can look on the standard deviation of the gray level in the square. Without a piece it would be quite low, so you could use some threshold here.
- You can do background subtraction with an empty square.

Either way, there will be some noise, so you will have to play with it a bit to find the best threshold/parameters.
Most of the time it is also better to do some pre-processing blur to get smoother results.

Comment: problem: what if piece is standing on a black field but its "head" occludes the white field at "top" of it, too (from the view of the camera)?

Comment: @Micka - Good point. I guess an obvious suggestion will be to take the image from a top view. A more complicated approach is to look on the upper and lower square of each detection. Then you could see the bottom and upper point of each piece.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that you need to consider:

- Is necessary to have that perspective of the chess?. A top perspective can help you to make your process easier, by doing this you are avoiding an invasion of a piece in other square.
- then you can check if there is a piece of chess in a square by checking the histogram of it. If the square doesn't have a piece you can appreciate a single peak in the curve, if there is a piece in that square you will appreciate more than one peak. You can use a threshold in the histogram to find if there is a single peak or not (by finding the max points in the histogram)